# WebView - Text Only?

Tags: html, xaml, text, webview, windows-runtime

Is there a way to make a WebView only load text in my WinRT XAML App? I would prefer an easier way than downloading the source and replacing img tags.

Answer (score 0):

What about using HttpClient to get the HTML and then display it using WebView.NavigateToString() ?

```
private async void DoMagic()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
        new Uri("http://www.example.com/"));
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    webView.NavigateToString(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of the WebView control. You will have to implement it yourself.